# Discord.js awaitReactions or on messageReactionAdd in private message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've created a system which allows users to send a poll in a channel and want to give them extra options in a private message. For this, I'm trying to toggle a poll option when the user reacts to this private message with an emoji.
The server part works perfectly fine, but I can't get the private message reactions to work as intended.

In summary: I'm trying to do something when the user reacts to a private message with an emoji. I've got this working perfectly fine for server channels.

To test this I've tried the following:

This first one doesn't seem to get called with private messages.

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log("added response");
});

client.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log("removed response");
});
```

This second one is test code that runs in response to the "!beep" command. Yet shows a few problems:

- The filter never passes and "collected" never gets logged.
- The filter only works after the reactions are added (I assume it's because of the async, but I want users to be able to toggle the option whenever they press on the reaction)
- The code doesn't get triggered when a reaction is removed (I assume this is because awaitReactions doesn't support that, but I want users to be able to toggle the option whenever they press on the reaction, regardless of whether they are adding or removing it)
- I tried removing the error bit, which logs "collected" after the time's up. But I want it to be responsive, and thus instant, and I also want it to be reusable so users can toggle it on and off.

```
const reactions = ["0️⃣", "1️⃣", "2️⃣", "3️⃣", "4️⃣", "5️⃣", "6️⃣", "7️⃣", "8️⃣", "9️⃣", ""];

        message.channel.send('@here Boop :robot:')
            .then(async (sentMessage) => {
                for (var i=0; i < reactions.length; i++) {
                    await sentMessage.react(reactions[i]);
                }

                ///////////////   TEST CODE!!!!
                const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                    console.log("filter called");
                    return true;
                };
                sentMessage.awaitReactions(filter, { time: 33000, errors: ['time'] })
                    .then(collected => {
                        console.log("collected");

                        const reaction = collected.first();
                        console.log(reaction.emoji);
                    })
                    .catch(collected => {
                        console.log("Time's up");
                    });

            });;
```

TLDR: I want to give a poll config panel to a user in a private message, that allows said user to toggle an option by clicking on a reaction to said config panel.

The stuff I tried didn't work. Am I doing something wrong? Is there some other way to do this? Or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging a bit more I found the problem, so in case anyone runs into an issue here;

These do work, I just had an if statement that got in my way XD.

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log("added response");
});

client.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log("removed response");
});
```

In case they don't work, the message isn't cached. For which the following give a good starting point (I haven't fully tried them though):

- https://gist.github.com/Danktuary/27b3cef7ef6c42e2d3f5aff4779db8ba
- https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/raw-events.md